# Facebook Limited login and retaining the access token between sessions

Tags: facebook, authentication, access-token

Should the limited login store the access token for future session?

I'm transferring my iOS app from classic login to limited login. But I can't get the auto-re-login to work.

Re-login with classic works correctly as docs says. "The FBSDKLoginManager sets this token for you and when it sets currentAccessToken it also automatically writes it to a keychain cache." The app r-logins correctly.

But with limited login it seems it doesn't store the token. Should is store? The docs are unclear whether limited login should do this or not.

Best, Hu

Comment: Hi, Hu Hund. Did an answer below help to clarify the things you asked? If so, could you kindly mark it as an answer? Otherwise, just point what's still unclear for you, and I'll update an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some points to proceed:

1. Limited Login mode doesn't provide you an **Access Token**. It provides you an **Authentication Token**. It's a regular JWT you can parse, but you are not able to use it for FB Graph API requests;
2. You can get the basic information about the user just by decoding this Authentication Token or using FB SDK right after signing in;
3. Currently, this token has an expiration of 1 hour, but you don't really need to refresh it every hour unless you need to get an update of the user information (for instance, to fetch a changed name, email, or a list of friends);
4. As you can see in the official blog post of Facebook, to refresh a token with information inside it, you need to **re-authenticate a user**, so call an SDK method to show FB popup. Reference: [FB: Announcing expanded functionality in Limited Login](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/04/12/announcing-expanded-functionality-limited-login/)

Currently, the official documentation is really unclear and has just a couple of pages related to the Limited Login mode. So if you still have any other questions, feel free to ask, I'll update the post.